# TypeError: schema._preCompile is not a function MongoDb problem

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I try to use a mongoose scheme I get the following error I can't find the solution.

TypeError: schema._preCompile is not a function

This is how the schema is defined.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const {isEmail} = require('validator')

const userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    validate: [isEmail, 'invalid email'],
    createIndexes: {unique: true},
    trim:true
  },
  nickName: 
  {
    type: String,
    require:true,
    createIndexes: {unique:true},
    trim:true
  },
  password: {
    type: String, 
    require:true,
    trim:true
  },
  dateBorn: {
    type: Date
  },
  games:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types,
    ref: 'Game' 
  }],
  books:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types,
    ref: 'Book' 
  }],
  movies:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types,
    ref: 'Movie' //referencia a things
  }],
},{
    timestamps:true,
    versionKey:false
  })
module.exports = mongoose.model('users',userSchema)
```

This is how I'm trying to import

```js
const usersSchema = require('../models/user')
```

This is how I define the connection

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const dbConnect = () => {
    const DB_URI= process.env.DB_URI
    const db = mongoose.connect(DB_URI,{
      useNewUrlParser:true,
      useUnifiedTopology:true
    }, (err, res) => {
      if(!err){
        console.log('CONECTION TO MONGODB SUCCESFULL')
      }else{
        console.log('CONECTION TO MONGODB ERROR')
      }
    })
  }


module.exports = { dbConnect }
```

[enter link description here](https://github.com/ManuelLatorre98/mycompletes)

here is the repository link for more information

Comment: The way you're declaring the types of the refs doesn't look right, you should be using a particular type such as `ObjectId`. See the docs for [SchemaTypes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

Comment: yep was that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
games:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types,
  }],
  books:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types,
  }],
  movies:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types,
  }],
```

In these lines you have to define what type of data you want to store here, like games could be a `String`also books could a `String/Array`. you just can't keep like `mongoose.Schema.Types` and think mongoose will choose it by it's own!!

have a read in this link - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html